# DVB-C stick works with OpenELEC, but not with OSMC

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, openelec, dvb, raspbmc

I'm not 100% sure whether this is the right site to ask, but I'll give it a shot.

I have a Raspberry Pi with [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) (f.k.a. RaspBMC, based on Raspbian) and [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net/) on it and it has been working perfectly for a long time. Now I bought a DVB-C/T/T2 TV tuner (PCTV tripleStick 292e) which claims to work with Linux [[1]](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_292e.html) [[2]](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/PCTV_Systems_tripleStick_T2_(292e)) because I want to run [Tvheadend](http://tvheadend.org/). I put the stick in my Pi, but Tvheadend just detected a DVB-T device (which is useless in my case - I need DVB-C). I downloaded various firmware files and put them into `/lib/firmware`, but that didn't change anything despite the firmware files being used. I spent hours trying to get DVB-C to work, but I failed.

Then I created another SD card with [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) on it, installed Tvheadend, and checked the web UI. The stick was detected as two devices, DVB-T and DVB-C. That's what I expected from various videos I found. In general, I don't mind changing from OSMC to OpenELEC, but the problem is that I can't install Pi-Hole on an OpenELEC device because OpenELEC is so minimalistic that it doesn't event have a package manager. Unfortunately, it's the only Pi OS I know that works with my DVB-C stick.

So does anyone have an idea how I can get my stick with OSMC/Raspbian to work? Or as an alternative: is it possible to combine Kodi, Tvheadend and Pi-Hole using another distribution, so it can be used as a media player "with extras" in the living room?